# How to get a Popup Window with Partial View in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

There seems to be a couple ways to do it. I really wanted this video to work for me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHWEs8XWA2U

Searching the web, I found it hard to find this question being asked recently, so I am wondering if newer and improved (easier) ways have been implemented.

Here is my Home controller

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult PartialViewTest()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PartialViewTest(Person person)
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my view I want the pop up on

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn-block" style="width:225px">Modal </button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-url='@Url.Action("PartialViewTest","Home")'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.btn-block').click(function () {

            var url = $('#myModal').data('url');
            $.get(url, function (data) {

                $("#myModal").html(data);
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Here is my partial view

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Bootstrap Dialog</h4>
            <div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="enter name" class="form-control" id="text" name="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="enter name id" class="form-control" id="text" name="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="adress" class="form-control" id="text" name="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnOK" onclick="">OK</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

[image: Page view when running]

When I click the button as seen in the image above. Nothing happens. Why doesn't the popup view appear?

If this is not the best way to go about it, could you provide a link to a tutorial for the most professional, proper, and easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: You should get familiar with the Developer Tools as soon as possible. Assuming you are using Chrome, look at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/. In short, we need you to tell us what errors, if any, you see there. The default template *already* loads jQuery and you are loading it again, so that's likely an issue

Comment: By the way, please do not add useless comments to your post. We all know that it's your first post and asking for people to look at a full GitHub repo is not welcomed here

Comment: Noted thanks Camilo.

Comment: Hi @DavidLaGrange, Your code is working fine for me. I think you have missed the bootstrap.js.  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

If this is Bootstrap then your partial view's modal HTML is broken. modal-body and modal-footer are under modal-header. I'm pretty sure modal-header, modal-body and modal-footer needs to be direct children of modal-content and that needs to child of modal-dialog and that needs to be child of modal and you have those container divs there wrapping them.

Edit:
Your problem is that you are loading your jquery and bootstrap after you try to use them. That `<script>` is run before your scripts are loaded. You need to put that into `scripts` section.

Camilo Terevinto notice you need remove jQuery script tag from your view. You already have jQuery in a bundle.

Answer (score 0):

"When I click the button as seen in the image above. Nothing happens. " -> I have just tried your code and it works, modal is openning. Has Camilo Terevinto comment you should press 12 in chrome, and check for errors in console tab.

After modal open, what is missing in your code?
Use "Person" model in modal, create a post form and set button ok to submit

```
@model Person //Should contain person model namespace
@Html.BeginForm("PartialViewTest", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
{
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Bootstrap Dialog</h4>
                <div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.name)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.adress)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnOK" onclick="">OK</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Your post action should redirect to Index.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialViewTest(Person person)
{
    /* do things */
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```